# ng-repeat boostrap-datepicker angular-strap $digest already in progress

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-strap

I'm using angular-strap directives and displaying datepickers in my loop, like here:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="myobject in myobjects">
    <div data-ng-if="myobject.category == 1">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="myobject.date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" bs-datepicker data-ng-change="update-myobject()"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my firebug console i can see that error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
minErr/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:78
beginPhase@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:11936
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:11733
.link/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular-strap.js:8
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3063
jQuery.event.add/eventHandle@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:2681
jQuery.event.trigger@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:2946
.trigger/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3604
.each@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:611
jQuery.prototype.each@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:241
.trigger@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3603
Datepicker.prototype._trigger@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js:300
Datepicker.prototype.update@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js:500
Datepicker.prototype.setStartDate@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js:396
$.fn.datepicker/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js:1124
.each@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:611
jQuery.prototype.each@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:241
$.fn.datepicker@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js:1102
.link/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular-strap.js:8
Attributes.prototype.$observe/<@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:5399
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:11634
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:11479
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:11740
done@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:7744
completeRequest@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:7918
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:49360/Scripts/angular.js:7877
```

If there is only one datepicker not inside ng-repeat it works fine. Any ideas? Or maybe I should use other datepicker?

Comment: I am working with strap v0.7.8, not able to reproduce your issue. The only suspicious is the `ngChange` attribute! What are you doing there? could this be removed? *NOTE: I tried the ui-bootstrap datepicker, but this one (strap) seems to be more fancy*

Comment: I'm using the same version of strap. I have removed the ngChange (I'm posting data there to api) but it didn't help? What dates are you getting there? When I look into my JSON it looks like "2014-01-05T01:00:00+01:00" maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I am using ISO as well and in that case, I had to add this attribute to the input: `<input ... data-date-type="iso" />`, so in fact, when I tried to reproduce your issue I added this setting there ;)

Comment: The error is here in angular-strap: `if (controller) {
                              element.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                                  scope.$apply(function () {
                                      controller.$setViewValue(type === 'string' ? element.val() : ev.date);
                                  });
                              });` when `scope.$apply` happens